# Matching variable value in pandas CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I have a CSV file with a list of Towns, Countys, and Country.

> ```
>                 Town           County  Country      
>             Ampthill     Bedfordshire  England      
>              Arlesey     Bedfordshire  England
> ```

I want to be able to check if a town is in the list, if a town is in the list then I want to know what the country is. 
Currently using pandas.

Any thoughts on how to check if a variable value is present in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('YOUR_PATH_HERE')

# to check if a single town
country = df.loc[(df['Town'] == 'Arlesey')]['Country']

# using the isin() operator
df.loc[df['Town'].isin(['Arlesey'])]['Country']
```

output:

```
1    England
```

using [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) is a very powerful tool for what you are looking for. It takes a list and returns `True` if the value is in the list. If you want the entire dataframe, just remove `['Country]` at the end:

```
     Town      County       Country
1   Arlesey Bedfordshire    England
```

If you need the actual values, you could use [`pd.series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html)

```
# using values[0] because it is the first element in the array
df.loc[df['Town'].isin(['Arlesey'])]['Country'].values[0]
```

Comment: @Jack, my pleasure. glad i could help! was it the output you were looking for?

Comment: I can work with it. Basically, I've got a web scraper that takes a list of cars and the towns they are located in. I want to be able to set each town to the correct County/Country for filtering purpose. The problem is the text may not be an exact match to the CSV list I've got, so I'll have to use a Fuzzy matching library and see if match >= 90%, then Town = Country.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: if you need a Fuzzy matcher i can suggest [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy). It does a very good job at exactly what you are trying to accomplish it uses [Levenshtein Distance](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm) as its fuzzy match.

Comment: Great, thanks! Appreciate you're help. Would you so the way I'm going about this is an appropriate way to do so?

Comment: @Jack, without some sample of what data is being brought back - I can say that you are probably on the right way. Pandas is very powerful so you can't go wrong there when you need to manipulate data and slice and dice. As for `fuzzywuzzy`, it can return some "off" results sometimes... If you need a real deep dive into text processing, look at [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/). This is a *very* heavy language processor and you can really hone in on solutions. What have/are you using for your web scraper?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into it with FuzzyWuzzy for now, seems like it provides enough functionality and I can deal with slight inconsistencies. 
Using custom scrapers built with Beautiful Soup then using psycopg2 to input results into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the value at the corresponding intersection:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

if 'ampthill' in df['town'].values:
    index = df.town[df.town == 'ampthill'].index.tolist()[0]
    country = df.loc[index, 'country']

print(country)
>>> england
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me...

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
home = str(Path.home())
csv_folder = Path(r"TO_CSV_FOLDER")


csv =  csv_folder / 'town-county-country.csv'
town = 'Ampthill'
with open(csv,'r') as csv:
    ctu = ["Town","County","Country"]
    cas = pd.read_csv(csv,usecols=ctu)
    index = cas.Town[cas.Town == town].index.tolist()[0]
    named = cas.loc[index, 'Country']
    print(named)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).